# Database restoration failed (Error detail: Login failed for user 'sa') Kindly, have a look on installation guide to complete candela installation

Tags: .net, sql-server, pos

I am trying to install candelarms pos system and I am getting the above error, anyone with ideas on how to fix it. I can not find the said specified instructions for windows 10

[image]

Comment: The error is pretty clear, if I am honest. "Login failed for user 'sa'". The credentials for your `sa` account were clearly wrong.

Comment: The problem is the database is bundled in the software @Larnu

Comment: If the software installs the instance, you need to speak to the vendor.